# Transform wrong when using both AVComposition and AVVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcomposition

I am creating an `AVMutableComposition`. I need the asset to be flipped horizontally, so I am setting the transform of the composition track like this:

```
compositionTrack.preferredTransform = assetTrack.preferredTransform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
```

If I export this (I use `AVAssetPreset960x640` as my preset), this works as expected.

However, I also need to add an `AVMutableVideoComposition` overlay to be rendered with this copmosition. This overlay shouldn't be flipped horizontally. I specify this like so:

```
// Create video composition
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(
    postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer,
    in: outputLayer
)

let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(
  start: .zero,
  duration: composition.duration
)
let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionTrack)
layerInstruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform, at: .zero)
    
instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
```

When I export the video with this, it isn't flipped horizontally. It stops the preferredTransform applied to the composition from being performed. Presumably it's this line that is causing this:

```
layerInstruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform, at: .zero)
```

If I set the layer transform to instead be `assetTrack.preferredTransform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)` or `compositionTrack.preferredTransform`, I'm presented with a black screen on export.

Apple have [these docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1744/_index.html) explaining transforms on an AVVideoComposition.  If I understand correctly, they say that I should just be setting the transform of the layer instruction. If I do that – applying a transform to the layer instruction and not the composition - I'm still presented with a black screen.

Why is this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: the transform that worked was

```
CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: videoSize.width, ty: 0.0)
```

---

So I ran into this issue a while back, following this RayWenderlich [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) (your code looks extremely familiar too!). The problem was that `assetTrack.preferredTransform` wasn't reliable, on some videos it would work, and on others it would be a black screen.

Instead of

```
let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionTrack)
layerInstruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform, at: .zero)
```

Try this:

```
func compositionLayerInstruction(for track: AVCompositionTrack, assetTrack: AVAssetTrack, orientation: UIImage.Orientation) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
    
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    let assetSize = assetTrack.naturalSize
    
    /// you should be able to play with these values to make a horizontal flip (try changing `a` and `d`)
    switch orientation {
    case .up:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, tx: 0, ty: 0)
    case .down:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(a: -1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: assetSize.width, ty: assetSize.height)
    case .left:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 0, b: -1, c: 1, d: 0, tx: 0, ty: assetSize.width)
    case .right:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 0, b: 1, c: -1, d: 0, tx: assetSize.height, ty: 0)
     default:
        print("Unsupported orientation")
    }
    
    instruction.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
    
    return instruction
}

let layerInstruction = compositionLayerInstruction(
    for: compositionTrack, assetTrack: assetTrack, orientation: videoInfo.orientation)
/// assetTrack is the original video
```

I based this off another answer on SO, can't remember where though.

Here's a helper function, to get `orientation`

```
/// adjust the video orientation is the source has a different orientation
private func orientation(from transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
    var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
    var isPortrait = false
    if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
    } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
    }
    return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
}
```

Full usage:

```
/// get adjusted orientation of the video
let videoInfo = orientation(from: assetTrack.preferredTransform)
let videoSize: CGSize

if videoInfo.isPortrait {
    videoSize = CGSize(
    width: assetTrack.naturalSize.height,
    height: assetTrack.naturalSize.width)
} else {
    videoSize = assetTrack.naturalSize
}


 /// the video
let videoLayer = CALayer()
videoLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)
        
/// overlay where you add graphics and other stuff
let overlayLayer = CALayer()
overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)

let outputLayer = CALayer()
outputLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)
outputLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
outputLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)

let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(
postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer,
in: outputLayer)

// MARK: - previous `let layerInstruction` code goes here...

instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

/// export session code here...
```

Comment: Yep I also followed that tutorial. Through a combination of your answer and some googling I worked out that the real transformation should be: `CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: videoSize.width, ty: 0.0)`. That should be applied to the layer instruction only, and not the compositionTrack. Might be worth updating your answer for anyone reading in the future :)

Comment: Nice! What do you mean by "applied to the layer instruction only, and not the compositionTrack"? Isn't that how it is already? Sure, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, does using `CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: videoSize.width, ty: 0.0)` not require switching `orientation`?